# Should I reuse context.Background() in go?

Tags: go, memory

Lets say I have 100 go routines that send gRPC request using context.WithDeadline(emptyCtx, ...)

Is there a reason for me to use the same global 'emptyCtx' for all child contexts?
`context.WithDeadline(emptyCtx, ...)`
or is it ok if I just use `context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), ...)`

I'm looking specifically memory-wise (investigate a memory leak)

Comment: If it's really only about passing `context.Background()` everywhere versus having one global _and unmodified_ `emptyCtx`, it really doesn't matter. That said, I would prefer the former as we'll be guaranteed to get a new copy of an empty context every time. I see two benefits to this: 1) when reading the code, there's no need to go back and see what `emptyCtx` is, and 2) there's no risk of someone coming along later that accidentally reassigns `emptyCtx` with, for example, a context with deadline (affecting the rest of the appplication)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing inherently bad happens if you call `context.Background` several times. [In 1.18 it returns the same single value every time](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/context/context.go;l=208), and there is little reason why that would change in the future.

In a code review, I would still question it, but only so it doesn't become a pain to add global deadlines or values later. It's just good practice to have context arguments in place.